# Finding Pandas row location

Tags: python, pandas

Say we have two dataframes, with one being a slice of the other.

If I'm iterating over the smaller DF, how do I find the index in the bigger DF, then find the row it is on?

So it would be something like this:

```
for idx in smaller.index:
    loc = bigger.ix[ix]**.row_location???**
    while not fin:
        looking_for_something = bigger.iloc[loc]
        if looking_for_something != criteria:
            loc += 1
        else:
            fin = 1
```

I'm sure it is something simple but I can't seem to locate the way to do this.

Comment: The index is the same in the slice, even if you change the columns, etc.  Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?

Comment: I commented on unutbu's answer, but the smaller is just a slice of the bigger. To C+P: I have a DF with up to millions of rows, and maybe 20 specific rows I need to find. Then I need to find an unspecified amount of rows after the 20 specific, using multiple criteria before I can know to stop iterating the rows directly after one of the 20 I find. I've accomplished this pretty easily, but now am looking for ideas to optimize

Answer (score 0):

If `smaller` is a slice of `bigger`, isn't all the information you are looking for in `bigger` already available in `smaller`?

If not, perhaps there are some columns in `bigger` not present in `smaller`. (Perhaps `smaller` should have been defined to include those columns?) In any case, you could use `pd.merge` or `smaller.join(bigger, how='inner', ...)` to match-up the rows in `bigger` with the rows in `smaller` that share the same index. This will accomplish in one fell swoop all the matches you are looking for with

```
for idx in smaller.index:
    loc = bigger.ix[ix]**.row_location???**
```

Moreover, it will be quicker. In general, performing operations row-by-row will not be the fastest way to achieve results. It is better to think in terms of joins or merges or groupbys or some such operation that works on whole arrays at a time.

Comment: I totally agree, but this situation is a little weird. I have a DF with up to millions of rows, and maybe 20 specific rows I need to find. Then I need to find an unspecified amount of rows after the 20 specific, using multiple criteria before I can know to stop iterating the rows directly after one of the 20 I find.

Comment: So knowing this, I think the fastest way is to be able to run a while statement given the row number and going one by one over them to find my criteria. Iterrows creates a whole new df so that seems way worse than just finding the row number from my match